# CSS box sizing to fit browser

Tags: html, css

I have a quick question. I want the box' width to adjust to however the browsers window size is. Basically I have this:

http://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/1abc17e8e79b2c3739599001d3fe50f4.png (image)

The code for this..

CSS:

```
#container {

}

#main-container {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.user-stats-container {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}   

#main-content {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    padding: 15px;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="notification-bar">
                notification bar Swag
            </div>

            <div id="container">

                <div id="side-bar">
                    <div class="side-bar-container">
                        side bar swag
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="main-container">

                    <div class="user-stats-container ">

                        user stats swag 

                    </div>

                    <div id="main-content">

                        Main content swag

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

the `main-content` is the div I want to adjust so that it goes across the screen - length wise but not too close to the end. I know for sure I need not to set a width to that, because it'll only limit it. If I'm not explaining this clearly, here's an example of what I'm talking about:

geedmo.com/ themeforest/ wintermin/ dashboard.html

notice how when you zoom out, the content still adjusts to the screen. That's basically what I want for my current `main-content` div.

here's a fiddle:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuwejwqv/)

I'm not entirely sure If I'm explaining myself, and I do apologize.

Thanks!

Comment: you want the whole thing to respond however big/small the screen is? Then are you talking about responsive design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kris,

What you want to accomplish you will need to use a percentage on the main-content div, as well as specify the width of its parent.

However, you have your side bar and content area set up a bit funky, this is why you have to margin the main content 200px to the left, and it will cause your attempts to make the site responsive quite difficult. What you will have to do:

side-bar and main-container will both need to be set to:

```
position:relative;
```

As well as get rid of all left and right margining.

Then set both containers to

```
float:left;
```

make your sidebar has a width of 20% or whatever size you feel fits best, and the main-container to 80%.

then set side-bar-container to position fixed

Comment: Justin is right, just an ammendment: You could also the css property 'calc', and set your right div to be calc: width(100%-200px) ... but check caniuse.com to check browser requirements

Comment: Calc is a great code to use. I find that using the display:flex; property works GREAT with a sidebar/main content combo.